# Is "I have much money." correct? If not, what is a one word synonym for "much" here?

Tags: word-request, synonyms

The only synonyms I can think of are **high** and **good**, but they seem incorrect.

PS: I am trying to avoid "a lot of".

Comment: The difficulty is that non-count "money" takes only a limited number of determiners in affirmative contexts, such as "some". And "much" is normally restricted to non-affirmative contexts. But you could use one of the adjectives that have a quantificational interpretation, such as "considerable", or perhaps "plentiful".

Comment: I object to all the suggestions above. None of the words "high", "good", "considerable" or "plentiful" can serve as a replacement for "much" in the sentence; they will only make it worse.

Comment: In fact, the only thing I can think of is "a lot of". Sorry.

Comment: @Mr Lister The OP asked for a single word and they specifically said they were trying to avoid "a lot of". There is nothing wrong with "I have considerable money"; not common perhaps, but there are attested examples; here's one: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jr7VUwY2vBsC&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=Can+I+say+I+have+%22considerable+money%22&source=bl&ots=U3jgfvXU2l&sig=KT8aMR_YdUto_6PG5n4axMBS4Bw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlkpv23-nQAhVkCsAKHZI0CMMQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=Can%20I%20say%20I%20have%20%22considerable%20money%22&f=false).

Comment: And here's another: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=vAov3ZsHoDoC&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=Can+I+say+I+have+%22considerable+money%22&source=bl&ots=dSU1O-evI-&sig=ddBZWG8yQjbeafixy6ESSDKeWzo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjavsDr4OnQAhWpDsAKHengDm4Q6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=Can%20I%20say%20I%20have%20%22considerable%20money%22&f=false)

Comment: Hmm... one word? How about *I have lotsa money!*? ;-) (Note that it's very informal.) -- On second thought, in informal English, *I have plenty money!* works just fine, too.

Comment: Lots of and a lot of is the most common (most idiomatic) way to say this...**No one actually says  in English: I have much money** in the declarative form even though it is a grammatically correct: plenty of money, enough money.

Comment: @Lambie "Even though it's grammatically correct" is an iffy assertion at best.  *Much* is a polarity-sensitive item and, as BillJ says, is usually restricted to non-affirmative contexts (*I don't have much money* but not *\*I have much money*).  Of course this would be incorrect if we said it's *never* used in affirmative contexts, but what we really need is a more nuanced description, not a simple claim that it is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use "much", but not by itself. The following is grammatical:

> I have so much money

If you really wanted a single word, you can use the idiomatic phrase ["big money"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/big-money):

> I have big money.

Or the dominantly British ["good money"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/good-money):

> I have good money.

---

You can also say:

> I have lots of money
>   I have tons of money
>   I have boatloads of money

Answer (score 0):

I have much money.

The sentence isn't ungrammatical, but it sounds unusual or too formal.

Much is mainly used in negative and interrogative sentences as follows:

I don't have much money.

Does he have much money?

As for another single word in place of much, you  can say:

I have considerable money

I have money galore.

There may some more adjectives, but I think all of them are not as idiomatic and common as the phrases a lot of, a large/considerable amount of, plenty of, etc. as follows:

I have a lot of money

I have a large amount ot money.

I have a considerable amount of money.

I have plenty of money.

Comment: Even more "common" is Harry Enfield's [Loadsamoney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loadsamoney). In which context, it's *common as muck*, with specific allusion to *where there's muck there's brass (money)*.

Comment: @Khan Yes, but the OP asked specifically for a one-word synonym for "much". The only possibilities are one or two of the adjectives that express a large amount like "abundant" and "considerable". But they have limited distribution and some people see them as being ungrammatical when used as modifiers of non-count noun like "money". Incidentally, there's nothing inferior about "a lot of"; in fact in many situations, it's the obvious logical choice.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with a lot of or lots of and those words are very commonly used in sentences like: I have [x] amount of money. One most certainly would want to use this.

Comment: Your last one in the best one, in my opinion: _I have plenty of money_.